# Is "as what...." a short from of "...so +adjective +that..." structure?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, comparison, metaphors

In a british movie, a boy is asking an old military man about his sword:

-Boy: Is that the sword you used in battles Mr.Poulter. Could I see it?

-The man(Mr.Poulter): Very dangerous weapon, my lad. ***An edge as what you could shave with.***

The structure "...as what..." in the sentence caught my attention. I have never seen such a structure for comparison. We were taught at school that we should use "so+adjective+that" structure for such comparisons.

I think the man means **"The edge is so sharp that you could even use it for shaving".(Or The edge is as sharp as a razor).**

If what I understand is correct, then can we say **"..as what..."** structure is a short form of **"...so+adjective+that..."** structure, which we were taught at school.

Thanks.

Comment: It's archaic and informal and hence defies the usual analysis. It has the meaning "an edge so sharp that you could shave with it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This construct is found in only a few dialects, and not in any of the standard ones.

You have the meaning right. There isn't an elided adjective *sharp*, it's just saying that the edge is the kind of edge you could shave with. You could also say "an edge *such as* you could shave with", or "an edge *of a sort* you could shave with", or just "an edge you could shave with".